# Create_user() in custom manager or save() method in Django custom user model for processing field before creating new record?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-managers

I have a Django custom user model with a save() method that tests for self.pk is None and does some extra processing to a field before creating a new user record. Is this the right place to put that or is it supposed to go into the create_user() method of the custom user manager? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

The point of save() and create_user() method is to save the object to the database. The difference is that the save() method need you to instantiate the object first, while create_user() automatically create the object and save into the database. There is no the absolute right way. You can use both of the as you want. Both method results are the same, add object to database.